# How to group the datas in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having three tables in sqlite trade,loan and advance in which i want to sum up all the total values of each table for each month suppose if the current month has zero records in loan then it should display it as 0 but when i used inner join concept the value gets doubled as well as the loan amount displays the total loans

**Trade table:**

```
String CREATE_FARMERTRADE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + FARMERTRADE_LABELS + "("
            + TRADE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + TRADE_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + TRADE_MOBNO + " TEXT,"
            + TRADE_COCONUTTYPE + " TEXT,"
            + TRADE_TOTALCOCONUT + " TEXT,"
            + TRADE_COCONUTCOST + " TEXT,"
            + TRADE_TOTALAMOUNT + " TEXT,"
            + TRADE_AMOUNTPAID + " TEXT,"
            + TRADE_BALANCEAMT + " TEXT" + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_FARMERTRADE_TABLE);
```

**Advance table:**

```
String CREATE_ADVANCE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + ADVANCE_LABELS + "("
            + ADVANCE_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + ADVANCE_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + ADVANCE_USERTYPE + " TEXT,"
            + ADVANCE_MOBNO + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
            + ADVANCE_AMOUNT + " TEXT,"
            + ADVANCE_REASON + " TEXT" + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_ADVANCE_TABLE);
```

**Loan table:**

```
String CREATE_LOAN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + LOAN_LABELS + "("
            + LOAN_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + LOAN_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + LOAN_USERTYPE + " TEXT,"
            + LOAN_MOBNO + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
            + LOAN_AMOUNT + " TEXT,"
            + LOAN_INTEREST + " TEXT,"
            + LOAN_PERIOD + " TEXT,"
            + LOAN_DUEDATE + " TEXT,"
            + LOAN_REASON + " TEXT,"
            + LOAN_TOTALAMOUNT + " TEXT" + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOAN_TABLE);
```

**Query:**

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT SUM(tradetotalamount) as totalamount, SUM(tradebalanceamount) as balanceamt, strftime('%m-%Y', tradedate) as 'month',SUM(advanceamount) as advanceamt, SUM(loanamout) as loanamt "+
            " FROM " + FARMERTRADE_LABELS + " INNER JOIN advancelabel ON farmertradelabel.mobileno = advancelabel.mobileno INNER JOIN loanlabel ON loanlabel.mobileno = farmertradelabel.mobileno  WHERE " + FARMERTRADE_LABELS + "." + TRADE_MOBNO + " = " + mobno + " " +
            "AND tradedate BETWEEN (select min(tradedate) from farmertradelabel) AND (select max(tradedate) from farmertradelabel)" +
            " GROUP BY strftime('%m-%Y', farmertradelabel.tradedate) ORDER BY strftime('%m-%Y', farmertradelabel.tradedate) DESC ";
```

How could i select all the three table values in a single table as well if a particular table doesn't have any value for that particular month then how i can show that value as zero?.thanks

Comment: check out here http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/ to deal with multiple tables and check the condition like  if the query returns nothing set values manually..or else use default constant for particular column.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)